# update nginx ingress from deployment to daemonset

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, daemonset

I installed nginx-ingress using helm. After that I notice the default `controller.kind` is `deployment` rather than `daemonset`, as I found in the [official doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/).

So how can I update the `controller.kind` from `deployment` to `daemonset` without reinstalling from the very beginning?

```
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.type=NodePort --set controller.service.httpPort.nodePort=30000 --set controller.service.httpsPort.nodePort=30443
```

Answer (score 5):

This might be helpful to you (--set controller.kind=daemonset).

```
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.type=NodePort --set controller.service.httpPort.nodePort=30000 --set controller.service.httpsPort.nodePort=30443 --set controller.kind=daemonset
```

Comment: I think this will reinstall the nginx-ingress, right? Do we have a light-weighted way, I mean no need to reinstall it.

Comment: You can use `helm upgrade` instead of `helm install` if you don't want reinstall it.

Comment: it should be `controller.kind=DaemonSet` - it's case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue today; the suggestion by vector didn't work for me but it was just a minor tweak required:

`helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.type=NodePort --set controller.service.httpPort.nodePort=30000 --set controller.service.httpsPort.nodePort=30443 --set controller.kind=DaemonSet`

(DaemonSet must be capitalized)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't capitalize DaemonSet and it removed all of my nginx pods -- so make sure you capitalize it! :-)